# Increase partition size with free space divided by another partition

Tags: partition, gparted

The attached screenshot shows my situation. I extended the virtual drive of my VirtualBox machine with one extra GiB, and now I would like to extend the sda1 partition with that extra space.

But I can't because of the extended partition in the way.

Is it possible to somehow overcome this problem?

[image]

Comment: Make the extended partition smaller first, make sure swap partition isn't mounted.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. Since I needed a quick fix, I ended up deleting the partition all together since gParted is unable to unmount. And it all still worked :) all good.

Comment: It is able to unmount, and it wasn't mounted in your screen shot in the first place.  You wouldn't be able to delete it if it was mounted, at least not without having to immediately reboot.  In the future, just expand the extended partition to the right, move the swap partition to the right, then move the start of the extended partition to the right.

Comment: @phk, it can't be made any smaller since it is entirely filled by the swap partition.

Comment: @psui: Right, first the swap partitions needs to be unmounted, then resized, then the extended one made smaller.

Comment: @psusi you are right the deletion part, I didn't touch a partition in 8 years, I don't remember a thing :D about the moving part, thank you for the clear explanation, I'll try it soon.

Comment: @phk consider answering this question so I can with the deletion and resizing so this question can get an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extended partition can't be changed unless its inner partitions are changed first. In your case the swap partition is in the way, which you would have to resize (or simply just delete it in your case, you can easily recreate it or use a swap file instead).

A common problem is that the swap partition can't be moved/removed because it's still mounted and used, in such a case you need to turn off that it's being used as a swap partition (e.g. using `swapoff`), no reboot required.

(It might be also worth noting that the extended partition stuff is not needed anymore when using the GPT partition scheme instead of MBR. Note that GPT is commonly used in conjunction with UEFI, whose support in VirtualBox used to be quite lacking, but from what I heard it improved in more recent versions.)